# Symfony doesn't validate form

Tags: php, forms, api, symfony, validation

I'm writing an API. And I need to validate the form. Other forms validate correctly, but this one does not validate at all.

This is my form type class:

```
public function buildForm(FormBUilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $builder
        ->add('passwordConfirmation', RepeatedType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'invalid_message' => 'Passwords must match!',
            'type' => PasswordType::class
        ]);
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
 public function configureOption(OptionsResolver $resolver){
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => RepeatPassword::class,
        'csrf_protection' => false
    ))
 }

public function getName() {
    return 'repeatPassword';
}
```

My entity:

```
class RepeatedPassword{
/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\Length(
 *    min = 8,
 *    minMessage = "Your password must be at least {{ limit }} characters long")
 * )
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $passwordConfirmation;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getPasswordConfirmation() {
    return $this->passwordConfirmation;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $passwordConfirmation
 */
public function setPasswordConfirmation($passwordConfirmation): void{
    $this->passwordConfirmation = $passwordConfirmation;
}
}
```

Method where I try validate:

```
public function resetPassword(Request $request): View{
    $form = $this->createForm(RepeatPasswordType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $this->userService->setPassword($this->getUser(), $form->getData()->getPasswordConfirmation());
        return View::create([], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

    return View::create($form->getErrors(), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
 }
```

My config.yml file:

```
 validation: { enabled: true, enable_annotations: true }
 serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
```

Data I send and server response with status 400:[image]

Comment: it's really much better if you paste your code in your question, even if its a lot. No one's going to have time to follow all those links.

Comment: Agreed, edit the question and paste your  code

Comment: $form->getData() return NULL, but should return object

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because screenshots of code are not acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen an issue before where `$form->handleRequest` was behaving differently to `$form->submit`. I was able to debug more effectively by manually calling submit.

```
$form = $this->createForm(RepeatPasswordType::class);
if ($request->getMethod() === 'post') {
    $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));
    if (!$form->isValid()) {
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, it's works. Now form validated, but form doesn't find my fields and I get error "This value should not be blank"

Comment: $form-getData() is empty

Comment: @AlexandrGraschenko - check `$request->request->get($form->getName())` has the data that should be submitted - it might be somewhere else in the request - but once you have it, submit that and it should have the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps:
add following to your form

```
'constraints' => [
                new NotNull(),
                new NotBlank(),
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

All I can see for now is that you have an extra "," at the end of your minMessage Assert. Have you tried removing it ?

Comment: This didn't help